# Help with approaching "advanced" Big-O problems

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

So an "advanced" problem in my mind may be easy to you but I am just starting to learn this so bare with me.

I want to find the best Big-O of the following problems:

1. $(15n+logn)^3$
2. $n^2logn + n + \sqrt n + logn$

When I look at these problems I find myself in an existential crisis, compared to problems like

Find best Big-O of $100n^2 + n$

Which is straightforward, in my mind.

I guess the part that trips me up is what do I do with the $log$'s and the $\sqrt n$'s?

I am just looking for advice on solving these problems. If you believe that solving for Big-O of the two problems listed will help me understand, then by all means solve them with explanations at each step but I am seeking help with approaching and understand what my first move should be with these problems. Thank you!

Comment: the definition is clear to you? you might want to add it anyway. For the first one consider to expand the term

Comment: When in doubt, you can just plug in a large value of $n$, say $n = 10^6$, and see what you get (e.g. using WolframAlpha). This will help you notice which terms dominate the asymptotic behavior and which terms you can ignore. When $n = 10^6$ we have that $n^2 = 10^{12}$ while $\sqrt{n} = 10^3$ and $\log_{10} n = 6$. So... which of these terms seems to be dominating?

Answer (score 1):

$\log(n)$ is smaller than any positive power of $n$. The $\sqrt{n} = n^{1/2}$ is smaller than $n$ but larger than $\log(n).$ If you had $n^{1/4}$ it would be smaller than $n^{1/2}$ or $n$ but larger than $\log(n).$

The second $n^2\log(n) + n+\sqrt{n}+\log(n)$ is probably the easiest to do since the terms are all there for you and you just need to find which one dominates. Of the last three $n,$ $\sqrt{n}$ and $\log(n),$ $n$ is the largest per last paragraph. But is it larger than $n^2\log(n)$? Well, $n^2\log(n)$ is larger than $n^2,$ so it's certainly larger than $n.$

For the first $ (15n+\log(n))^3$ you can multiply it out, and then you have four terms to compare. Or note that the $n$ term dominates the $\log(n)$ term, and infer which of the four terms is going to be the leading order.

Answer (score 1):

One simple fact that will help you most big-O problems we encounter in practice:

$n^\alpha$ is larger (in big-O sense) than $\log n$ for any $\alpha > 0$. $n^{1/2}, n^{1/3}, n^{1/10},$ and so on, are all larger than $\log n$.

[spaceisdarkgreen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/397125/spaceisdarkgreen])'s answer shows how to use this fact.

Answer (score 0):

The limit test is a helpful formalism. Let $f, g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be functions. Let:

$$L := \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$$

If:

- $L = 0$, then $f(n) \in o(g(n))$. Note that this is little-o vs. Big-O, which is a stronger condition. Now if $f(n) \in o(g(n))$, then $f(n) \in O(g(n))$.
- $0 < L < \infty$, then $f(n) \in \Theta(g(n))$, so $f(n) \in O(g(n))$.
- $L = \infty$, then $f(n) \in \omega(g(n))$, which implies that $f(n) \in \Omega(g(n))$. Note that if $f(n) \in \Omega(g(n))$, then $g(n) \in O(f(n))$.

Now for your example. Let $f(n) = (15n + \log(n))^{3}$ and let $g(n) = n^{3}$. We have that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 15^{3}$$

So $f(n) \in \Theta(g(n))$, which implies that $f(n) \in O(g(n))$.

As you do more of these problems, you will develop better intuition for how to eyeball the dominant term. It is always nice/important to be able to formally prove your intuition, though.